# Convert long date format in text for non english language in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with the current date Dutch using =today() in long format. So my result is 'dinsdag 01 januari' (without the quotes) and I want to retrieve the word 'dinsdag' (Tuesday) for further comparison. 
But as the formula =today gives a number, I need to force a conversion of the date into text. I have tried with =text(today(),"dddd") but the result is the string Tuesday (in English) so it gives a different result.

Is there a method to convert the date using =today() in another language into text to get the string 'dinsdag' instead of 'Tuesday'? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you do a custom format through the ribbon menus of `dddd`? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you? If so please mark as one as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used.

Comment: Hello, Thanks @teylyn for your answer. I tried them both and both worke well. I will have to mark one as correct but just for the simplicity and because it was the first answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"[$-413]dddd")
```

The `[$-413]` is the hexadecimal code for Dutch.  See [HERE](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) for full list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula is a good start. Use it inside a lookup table with two columns: English and Dutch

```
=vlookup(text(today(),"dddd"),Sheet1!$a$2:$b$8,2,false)
```

[image]